# TypeScriptのObjectで状態定義を型安全にしつつ、必要のない状態は定義を簡略化したい

Tags: typescript

（ちょっとタイトルがわかりにくいのはわかっています。表現が難しいのでもう少し練ります）

String Literalで定義されている`Status`に対応する値を定義するために、`statusMap`というものを以下のように定義します。

```
export type Status = "SOME_TEXT" | "HELLO" | "GOOD" | "RANDOM";

type ValueObject = {
    text: string;
};

const statusMap: Record<Status, ValueObject | undefined> = {
    "SOME_TEXT": {
        text: "status 1",
    },
    "HELLO": {
        text: "status 2",
    },
    "GOOD": undefined,
    "RANDOM": undefined,
    // どんどん増える
};
```

このとき、`Status`に新しい状態が増えると`statusMap`が型エラーとなり、その時の振る舞いを実装者が決めるように促すことができます。

しかしながら、例にあるように`SOME_TEXT`と`HELLO`は値が決まっているが、それ**以外**の値が`undefined`で決まっている場合に、`Status`の種類が増えるたびに実装させるのは冗長になっていきます。例えば数1000も状態があるとそれをすべて実装することになるのは面倒。

そこで、if/switchなどを利用し、することで"SOME_TEXT"と"HELLO"以外のすべてを`undefined`にすることはできます。
ただしこれは新しい`Status`が追加されたときにすべて`undefined`の状態になるだけで、本当に必要な変更を見逃す可能性があります。

```
const getStatusValue = (status: Status): ValueObject | undefined => {
  switch (status) {
    case "SOME_TEXT": {
      return {
        text: "status 1",
      };
    }
    case "HELLO": {
      return {
        text: "status 2",
      };
    }
    default: {
      return undefined;
    }
  }
};
```

今求めているのは、

- 新規の`Status`が定義されたときに、値が定義されていないことを型エラーで検知したい
- 既存の状態が`undefined`の部分は値の定義をスキップしたい。

です。このような型定義の方法はありますか？

Comment: undefinedが増えていくのと、クラスのinterfaceの肥大化で不要なoverride/implementsが増えていく症状は似ています。本来共用するべきでないところでstatusを使用しているのが根本問題に見えるので、使用範囲に合わせてstatus自体を何段階かに分けるべきではないでしょうか？

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。「本来共用するべきでないところで...」ですが、このstatusがバックエンド由来のもので、フロントエンドがそのstatusに応じた状態を定義したいような場合だとコントロールできないので、これが実現できない場合もあると考えられます。

少し自分の方でも考えてみましたが「変更を検知する」という部分は型定義でチェックする以外にもスナップショットテストでStatusの増減のチェックを任せてしまう、というような方法も検討しています。型定義の方は利用する範囲でのみ定義する、と棲み分けも必要かな、と考えています。